# javascript submit() not submitting form

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, so my error may be extremely basic. I did look at similar posts and could not figure out what I am doing wrong with my code.

```
<form name=dform_8190 method="get">
<input type="submit" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name=delete_id id="delete_id">
```

some other code here

```
<a onclick="if (confirm('Delete Comment 8190?')) {document.getElementById('delete_id').value=8190; document.getElementById('dform_8190').submit();}">
<img SRC="../images/del_x.png" ALT="archive" title="Archive" border="0">
</a>
</form>
```

the "Delete Comment 8190" box pops up, but when I select "OK", nothing happens.

Comment: I believe that the problem is `METHOD="GET"` which should be `METHOD="POST"`

Comment: Getting an error in the console that submit is not a property of undefined?

Comment: You're using `getElementById` for a `name`... That won't work. Change `<form name=dform_8190 method="get">` ==> `<form id=dform_8190 method="get">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form doesn't have an ID of `dform_8190`. You need to add it. Or change your query to

```
document.querySelector("form[name=dform_8190]").submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change name to id: . 
getElementById uses value of "id" attribute.